# How to prevent "Community bot" fiddlings from (uselessly) messing the TOP QUESTIONS order?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, community

Let's have an example taken from now :

This thread ( [No Wifi adapter found - HP Laptop - Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592135/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptop-ubuntu-18-04-4-lts) ) is being popped up by the community bot asserted modified some minutes ago.

Looking at the thread, I just cannot view any sort of re-edit or modification from the community bot. (or any other sort of modification in the question / answer / comments by other "honest" U&L SE contributor for years)

My opinion is that is definitely a undue up! (since there has not been any added value to the thread) that I would like to avoid messing the TOP QUESTIONS order.

---

**EDIT :** Jeff's suggestion to prefer WEEK / MONTH lists in comments actually & appropriately answers this question

Comment: That's a normal bump from the Community user because that question doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer.

Comment: Maybe you would prefer the Hot, Week, or Month sun-tabs instead of the Active one?

Comment: @JeffSchaller : <trolling>One should suggest the so called "Community user" to offer a bounty then. :-P </trolling> Anyway ! Thanks for your suggestion of preferring Week / Month lists. I had not tested and it just indeed solves this problem of disgraceful bumps.

Comment: Sorry you see the bumps as disgraceful; because it's not apparent in the U&L Help Center, here's the Meta.SE FAQ about bumps: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped

Comment: @JeffSchaller : Thanks for the link… as part of which I can read that SE sites get some control over the rate "*The maximum number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site*" Since yes! bumps are disgraceful whoever initiates them and since I can hardly  find that these bumps actually trigger new activity from "real-honest" users, if you get access to objective statistics confirming that, you could probably decide to lower their frequency.

Comment: "disgraceful"!? Wow. Don't you think you might be overreacting a little? This is a standard mechanism that ensures old questions are not forgotten and can still be answered. I really don't understand why you find this bothersome, let alone why you would go so far as to call it "disgraceful". All it does is help get eyes on old questions so they have a chance of being answered. Why do you use the "Home" view if you don't like this so much? Just go to the "Questions" link on the left side bar instead of "Home" to see questions by date posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question in your title is mostly answered by [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped) over on Meta.SE -- it's desired behavior on the part of Stack Exchange in order to get more questions answered by putting unanswered questions in front of visitors. I wasn't sure how effective that mechanism was on our site, so I dug around on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and found this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/634223/how-effective-are-community-bumps and threw a few sites at it. This is the output from that today:

| site | number of bumps | percent effective | voted after bumped | answered after bumped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U&L | 8284 | 5.4 | 371 | 91 |
| DBA | 8239 | 4.7 | 327 | 72 |
| SF | 16566 | 3 | 425 | 85 |
| SU | 16549 | 2.9 | 387 | 102 |
| AU | 8279 | 2.4 | 160 | 41 |
| SO | 33225 | 2.3 | 615 | 190 |

It seems to me, based on that query & data, that the bumping on U&L is among the most effective among those sites at getting questions answered & getting those answers voted on. I suspect there'd be some resistance to disabling the Community bump limits in the face of this.

Instead, I'd recommend changing your view into the site by going to one of these other links:

- the [Questions view](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions)
- the Top Questions of the [week](https://unix.stackexchange.com/?tab=week) or [month](https://unix.stackexchange.com/?tab=month).

It sounds like the Questions view might be what you're expecting -- where it's simply the newest questions that have been asked, in order.

While I'm here, I'll mention a feature that I discovered recently: the Filter button on the Questions view; in particular, there's an option there to select questions that are tagged with "My watched tags"; from there, you can decide whether you want to include questions that don't have any answer or that don't have an *accepted* answer, etc. When questions are tagged appropriately, people then have an easier time finding questions they'd like to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff (and of course +1) for sharing this objective view. (<trolling>which, as part of the *voted after bumped* does not isolate the downvotes performed  in order to reduce the chances of questions to get bumped again… :-P </trolling>) Anyway, My intention was not to challenge your choices (since you actually offered alternative methods to view site's active Q&As) At most would I go on ranting regarding the "*modified*" word regarding the "Community user"'s that did not actually *modified* anything (valuable)

Comment: Happy to share; hopefully the SEDE query is representative! I didn't write it :)  I mainly wanted to share information on how SE works; it was built before I got here, and I'm constantly learning (and re-learning!) how it works. Seeing "modified" without a change is surprising... until you learn what's going on. It would make more sense if that bump said something different, like "bumped 3 minutes ago", but I *suspect* there's a list of options for that text that is: "$user - $rep - (asked | answered | modified) - $time ago" and "modified" was the best choice of those.

Comment: @terdon : No hardfeeling & without any disrespect : /modified/s//usurped modified/ in my comment above. ;-)

Comment: Note that there *are* instances of modified posts where you won’t see any activity (unless you happened to have the post already open); for example, if an answer is deleted, or if a comment is added and then deleted.