# U&L Help Center article for our policy on AI-generated content

Tags: discussion, answers

*Minutes* after I posted [Do we want to enable an "AI-generated content" banner?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7184/do-we-want-to-enable-an-ai-generated-content-banner), the [Main Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/395881/revisions) was updated to ask us to fill in the "Learn more" link with our site's policy on AI-generated content.

I wish I had been a little slower to post our question, and/or more careful to notice that there was a dead "Learn more" link that obviously needed something behind it, and so I apologize for the Meta spam here.

Are we good with using a copy of [SO's "Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) page here? It starts with:

> Artificial Intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools may not be used to generate answers for Stack Overflow. The answers you provide must either be your own original work, or the properly cited work of others. If your answers are determined to have been written by AI, they will likely be deleted, along with any reputation earned from them.

... which sounds to me like it captures the idea behind our [previous discussion on AI](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6021/how-do-we-want-to-handle-ai-generated-answers).

To keep things simpler for this round, please upvote this Question if you agree with this idea; downvote and/or discuss if you disagree. Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a good plan.

Comment: Seems fine. I wonder if there would be a value in distinguishing spell / grammer assistants ([Grammerly](https://www.grammarly.com/)?) from AI generated.  Or do we just leave that to people's common sense?

Comment: I could squint and say that a grammar tool did not *generate* the answer, but rather *corrected* the author's text.